# reloadData wont call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

I got myself in a problem that I cant find a solution to, so if someone can help me I would appreciate it. I've read a lot of posts on what could be the problem but I did not found any solution.
I have a .h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
    UITableView *myTableView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UITableView *myTableView;
@end
```

and a .m

```
@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize myTableView;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
    myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    myTableView.rowHeight = 325;
    myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [myTableView setDelegate:self];

    [myTableView setDataSource:self];
    [myTableView registerClass:[MTTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self separateByType];

}
-(void)separateByType
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempUrl];
            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setDelegate:self];
            [request startAsynchronous];
}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    SBJsonParser *jsonReader = [SBJsonParser new];

    firstJsonData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    firstJsonData = [jsonReader objectWithString:response error:nil];

    NSLog(@"Calling reloadData on %@", self.myTableView);

    [self.myTableView reloadData];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[firstJsonData objectForKey:@"data"] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    MTTableViewCell *cell = (MTTableViewCell *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MTTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.titleTextlabel setText:[JSONDATA objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [cell.descriptionTextlabel setText:[JSONDATA objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection: is returning 0 or nil then

Comment: How do you know it's not getting called? Is this a copy and paste? You haven't declared `CellIdentifier` in cellForRow

Comment: NSArray* jsonArray = [firstJsonData objectForKey:@"data"]; NSInteger numberOfRows = [jsonArray count]; NSLog(@"Count: %i", numberOfRows); return numberOfRows;

Comment: the only reason why cellforrowatindexpath would be not be called is generally for 2 reasons, numberofrows returns 0 or the tableview somehow got deallocated in that time frame between cellforrow and numberofrows

Comment: number of rows is returning 98. cellidentifier is declared as static `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";`

Comment: you have a strong reference to the tableview and you set the datasource so those reasons are already verified

Comment: it cant be deallocated because I have put a yellow background that I see when the view is loaded, but no data is shown

Comment: Why are you setting the table view's datasource and delegate twice? You don't need to check for an existing cell when you dequeue it if you are registering the class.

Comment: i've tried both ways, with and without setting this things. No result.

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection` try logging the value of `tableView` and of `myTableView` to verify that they are the same thing.

Comment: they are not the same, I have two tables... thx @PhillipMills, I realized the problem now.

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from  to help me improve my questions. If it's not to much trouble can the person who downvoted my question (or anyone) explain to me what I did wrong, so it won't happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare ivar `UITableView *myTableView`

Don't `@synthesize myTableView`

Always access `myTableView` via the property accessor `self.myTableView`

Answer (score 3):

First Of All , Your code should run well.

- Be Sure that numberOfRowsInSection function should return valid number.
- Be Sure that "myTableView" is not nil.
- Be sure that "myTableView" is seen as background yellow?

Comment: read comments @Mehmet, I know it should run well, I checked and writen the point about `numberOfRowsInSection` I also wrote about the yellow collor so the next two points are ridiculous. There was a IBOutlet that I have forgotten about and it draw the reload to it, instead to the actual table.

Comment: Thanks this helped me, I forgot to even look at number of rows in section which was quite obviously the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

    [self.tableView reloadData]; not working 

}

- (void)reloadTable {

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

above code works for me reload table in selector method.